# set apache to allow traffic from 1 IPv6 address

Tags: centos, apache-2.4

I am trying to set up a apache to only allow users from a specific ip address. This are the directives for `/var/www/html` directory

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Options -Indexes
    <RequireAll>
       Require ip 2b00:ff2:600:8200::/64
    </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

It unfortunately blocks traffic from my ip as well. I am seeing default apache website, although I've set an index.html file. Any idea what is the correct directive to allow traffic just from 1 ipv6? I am using apache 2.4.6

Answer (score 2):

Although it does not answer your question regarding this in specific to Apache, this would usually be done with the ip6tables packet filter to filter traffic to the destination IP and/or port that Apache is running on:

If your default policy was to drop in iptables you'd use this:

```
ip6tables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport <port> -s 2b00:ff2:600:8200::/64 -j ACCEPT
```

Else you could drop any data not from that IP, to the port.

```
ip6tables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport <port> -s ! 2b00:ff2:600:8200::/64 -j DROP
```

else if you wanted to block all other IP and not use a default policy of drop within your ip6tables rules, then since ip6tables is a match first packet filter you would just add a DROP rule after the first rule:

```
ip6tables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport <port> -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in an EC2 instance ? If so, just setup a security group to allow traffic on port 80 from only a certain IP.

Comment: nope, on a dedicated server